# How to change primary LDAP domain of WSO2 IS 4.5.0

Tags: ldap, apacheds, ldap-client, wso2-identity-server

I would like modify **the domain of the primary user storage** (based on LDAP), but i can not get successfully.

The current domain in `user-mgt.xml` is `dc=wso2,dc=org` and I would like to change to `dc=foobar,dc=com`

My modified `user-mgt.xml` is:

```
...
    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>

            <Property name="defaultRealmName">FOOBAR.COM</Property>

            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                                   
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
            <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>

            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=foobar,dc=com</Property>

            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="ServicePasswordJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="ServiceNameJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{2,30}/[\\S]{2,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>

            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=foobar,dc=com</Property>

            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>

            <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=foobar,dc=com</Property>

            <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>

            <Property name="UserDNPattern">uid={0},ou=Users,dc=foobar,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="RoleDNPattern">cn={0},ou=Groups,dc=foobar,dc=com</Property>

            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
...
```

The error when starting WSO2 IS is:

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
        baseDn : 'ou=Groups,dc=foobar,dc=com'
        filter : '(&(2.5.4.0=groupofnames)(2.5.4.3=*))'
        scope : whole subtree
        typesOnly : false
        Size Limit : 100
        Time Limit : 11
        Deref Aliases : deref Always
        attributes : 'cn'
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for ou=Groups,dc=foobar,dc=com]
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.getLDAPRoleNames(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1024)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doGetRoleNames(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleNames(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2485)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleNames(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2382)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleNames(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2375)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.subscription.registry.RegistrySubscriptionManager.<init>(RegistrySubscriptionManager.java:91)
    ... 65 more
```

What should I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved !

I have replaced older domain and `defaultRealmName` in the following files:

1. `IS_HOME/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml`
2. `IS_HOME/repository/conf/tenant-mgt.xml`
3. `IS_HOME/repository/conf/embedded-ldap.xml`

I have replaced `dc=wso2,dc=org` for `dc=foobar,dc=com` and `defaultRealmName=WSO2.ORG` for `FOOBAR.COM`, then I deleted the directory named `root` located in the `IS_HOME/repository/data/org.wso2.carbon.directory`
.. so a fresh default partition will be created again at the restart.

Now, if you connect to WSO2IS' embedded LDAP (10389 port) using any LDAP client, you will see the new domain `FOOBAR.COM` instead of `WSO2.ORG`.

I hope that be useful.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, consider accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to change the "dc=wso2,dc=org" value. You can not change it using user-mgt.xml file.  user-mgt.xml file is used to connect WSO2IS with LDAP or AD or JDBC user stores. It means there can be LDAP running externally and you need to configure user-mgt.xml file to connect that LDAP using proper configurations. By default WSO2IS is shipped with embedded LDAP server  and by default user-mgt.xml file has been configured to point to that embedded LDAP server. This embedded LDAP is created with "dc=wso2,dc=org" value. You can find the configurations of this embedded LDAP in the "embedded-ldap.xml" file.  But there is no parameter to configure the domain ""dc=wso2,dc=org".  It means, we can not configure it. But you can still create your own LDAP server using ApacheDS, OpenDJ and OpenLDAP and can point it to WSO2 Identity Server.