# wso2 IS embedded ldap new partition

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am currently using WSO2 IS version 4.0.0, trying to add a new partition to default Embedded Ldap server (apacheds) using apache directory studio v2.0. So far not successful in creating new partition. Appreciate if someone can help me with right steps?

Comment: Is it possible to modify wso2 embedded ldap schema structure? Or should I be installing a new apacheDS and configure wso2IS to use new apacheDS as external ldap server?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to create a new partition, but however I renamed existing partition by following the steps mentioned here ...

[How to change primary LDAP domain of WSO2 IS 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990594/how-to-change-primary-ldap-domain-of-wso2-is-4-5-0)